# Laravel Artisan command in controller ignores additional options

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to run an Artisan command from a controller with options to either run parallel or test a single test class:

```
$this->call('test', [
    '--parallel',
    '--filter' => 'FooTest',
]);
```

But it just ignores any options. If I run `php artisan test --filter=FooTest` or `php artisan test --parallel` in the command line this works just fine.

I've tried using `Artisan::call( ... )`, put the array in a variable, use `array()` instead of `[]` but nothing seems to work.

But when I run a seeder **with options** it works just fine

```
$this->call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'EssentialDatabaseSeeder']);
```

Comment: How are you determining that it "ignores the options"? What debugging have you done? Running `php artisan test --parallel --filter=FooTest` to test seems like an obvious step. Add details to your question, such as  the output of `dd($this->options())`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to pass a boolean value to the Artisan command, you need to do the following:

```
$this->call('test', [
    '--parallel' => true, // Add true here
    '--filter' => 'FooTest',
]);
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#passing-boolean-values):

> **Passing Boolean Values**
> If you need to specify the value of an option that does not accept string values, such as the `--force` flag on the `migrate:refresh` command, you should pass `true` or `false` as the value of the option:

Comment: If that doesn't solve your issue, it would be ideal to include the bare bones of your Artisan command code in your question as it might provide additional clues for what might be causing the issue.

Comment: The parallel part is the same when I use the inline command, so that part is working (which is the main part of my problem).

However the filter is still not working. I have 74 tests in total -in 4 different classes- and when I filter for a single class I expect the numbers of test ran to be 3, 17, 17 or 37 tests but I always get "74 passed". I have to say that single class testing will only be done while writing tests so it's not all that important since the console command still works.

Comment: If the above doesn't work for you then you may pass the entire Artisan command to the call method as a string:

Artisan::call('test --parallel --filter=FooTest');

Comment: @Botnetdobbs somehow this only works for parallel. It's as if the command refuses or just ignores the filter

Comment: Jup, can confirm that filter is not respected. Neither inline nor as a argument in the `$parameters` array of the method signature.